# Change [publishing-family-history] tag to just [publishing]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Should we change [publishing-family-history](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing-family-history) to just [publishing](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing)?

Answer (score 4):

Could this tag be further defined: like online-publishing, book-publishing etc?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Questions about publishing anything else would be off topic. Having the "family-history" piece seems like overkill to me.

Comment: I agree. It's utterly pointless. Off with family history!